# Why constructor of component vectors is called in multivector template?

Tags: c++

```
template<size_t dimcount, typename T, size_t vecSize >
class multiVector {
    private:
        std::vector< multiVector<dimcount - 1, T, vecSize>> vec;
    public:

        multiVector() : vec(vecSize) {
            multiVector<dimcount - 1, T, vecSize>(); // Why?
        }
};

template<typename T,size_t vecSize>
class multiVector<1, T,vecSize> {
    private:
        std::vector<T> vec;
    public:

        multiVector() : vec(vecSize) {}
};
```

Why calling constructor of component vectors is neccessary here? From my understanding, they should get called automatically where `vec` is declared.

Comment: Why do you say it's necessary ? That code makes no sense regardless, as all that line does is default construct, then discard, a single `multiVector<dimcount - 1, T, vecSize>` instance. Fyi, they don't get "called automatically where `vec` is declared"; they get called when `vec` is *constructed* in the member-init list, which is easily provable with some instrumented output in the constructor bodies. I'm curious where you're actually creating your top-level instance, and with what `dimcount` and `vecSize` you're doing it, because there can quickly be a *ton* of vectors created from this.

Comment: @WhozCraig This piece of code was in Microsoft's C++ course discussing multidimensional vector. I guess this is just another instance of the authors' incompetence.

Comment: That *has* to be a typo.